# right click context menu on gridcontrol does not stay open in debug

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, gridcontrol, devexpress-wpf

I am running latest Visual Studio 2019 16.2.5. While debugging my app, grid control right click context menu does not stay open, it closes immediately. But while running without debug, it works fine. This has started with recent updates in Visual Studio 2019.

```
    <dxg:GridControl x:Name="gcgrid" AutoPopulateColumns="False">
        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="First" AllowEditing="False"  />
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Second" />
        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView UseLightweightTemplates="None">
            <dxg:TableView.RowCellMenuCustomizations>
                <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="MenuItemDocketEdit" Content="Edit"  />
            </dxg:TableView.RowCellMenuCustomizations>
            </dxg:TableView>
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue has been fixed in the context of the [PopupMenus are immediately closed after they have been opened when UI Debugging Tools for XAML are enabled in Visual Studio 2019 (v16.2)](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T801672/popupmenus-are-immediately-closed-after-they-have-been-opened-when-ui-debugging-tools) thread. Please try updating your DevExpress components to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that DevExpress have already fixed this issue in the context of the PopupMenus are immediately closed after they have been opened when UI Debugging Tools for XAML are enabled in Visual Studio 2019 (v16.2). upgrade your current major version to 18.2.10 and check if the issue still occurs.

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T815540/right-click-context-menu-on-gridcontrol-does-not-stay-open-in-debug